# What's the difference between JSON.load and JSON.parse methods of Ruby lib?

Tags: ruby, json

From the ruby document I can see that `load` method takes a proc as arg while `parse` doesn't. Is there any other difference? Say, when I have a string of JSON, which method should I use to turn it into a Ruby object?

> **load(source, proc = nil, options = {})**
> Load a ruby data structure from a JSON source and return it. A source can either be a string-like object, an IO-like object, or an object responding to the read method. If proc was given, it will be called with any nested Ruby object as an argument recursively in depth first order. To modify the default options pass in the optional options argument as well.
> This method is part of the implementation of the load/dump interface of Marshal and YAML.
> Also aliased as: restore
>
> **parse(source, opts = {})**
> Parse the JSON document source into a Ruby data structure and return it.

Comment: ". If proc was given, it will be called with any nested Ruby object as an argument recursively in depth first order"

Comment: Compare JSON's interface with Marshal's and reread the `load` docs again. Then look at the [`load` source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/ext/json/lib/json/common.rb#L308).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I know `proc` is optional. I got this question because I used to convert a JSON string by `JSON.parse`, but I watched a screencast which used `JSON.load open('http://some.url').read`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`JSON#parse` parses a JSON string into a Ruby Hash.

```
 JSON.parse('{"name": "Some Name"}') # => {"name" => "Some Name"}
```

`JSON#load` takes either a string or IO (file etc) and converts that to Ruby Hash/Array

```
JSON.load File.new("names.json")     # => Reads the JSON inside the file and results in a Ruby Object.

JSON.load '{"name": "Some Name"}'    # Works just like #parse
```

In fact, it converts any object that responds to a `#read` method. For example:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = '{"name": "Some Name"}'
  end

  def read
    @a
  end
end

JSON.load(A.new)                      # => {"name" => "Some Name"}
```

Comment: I was confused because seeing some guy used `JSON.load open('http://...').read`. Now I know `parse` and `load` both work on `String`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah. `open-uri` has that `open` method that returns an IO object from a link.

Answer (score 27):

A key difference is that `JSON.load` is unsafe when given untrusted input (the same can be achieved with `JSON.parse`, but it has safe defaults). This is because it provides a way to instantiate classes other than the "normal" Hash, String, Array, Number classes:

```
class Foo
  def self.json_creatable?
    true
  end
  def self.json_create attributes
    puts "called with #{attributes}"
  end
end

JSON.parse('{"json_class": "Foo"}') #=> {"json_class"=>"Foo"}
```

whereas

```
JSON.load('{"json_class": "Foo"}')
called with {"json_class"=>"Foo"}
#=> nil
```

This intended for you to implement custom serialization of data - it shouldn't be used when parsing data from the wide world. Of course you do need to implement the `json_creatable?` and `json_create` methods for this to actually achieve anything, but how confident are you that none of your dependencies do this or implement `method_missing` in such a way that it could be misused ? (see for example the [`Marshal.load`](https://github.com/charliesome/charlie.bz/blob/master/posts/rails-3.2.10-remote-code-execution.md) exploits. As a result of this `JSON.load` & `JSON.parse` were tightened up significantly).

Always use `JSON.parse` when dealing with untrusted data or unless you need the extra capabilities of `JSON.load`

Answer (score 20):

One more difference is that `JSON.load` parses single value (not object and not array) by default.

```ruby
JSON.load("false")
=> false

JSON.load("123")
=> 123
```

But `JSON.parse` requires `quirks mode` to be enabled to parse such value.

```
JSON.parse("false")
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at 'false'

JSON.parse("false", quirks_mode: true)
=> false
```

Comment: This is no longer true. In Ruby 2.4.1 `JSON.parse("false")` works just fine; I guess `quirks_mode: true` becomes the default.

Answer (score 2):

Here `load` the source codes [click me](https://devdocs.io/ruby~2.6/json#method-i-load)

```rb
# File ext/json/lib/json/common.rb, line 323
def load(source, proc = nil, options = {})
  opts = load_default_options.merge options
  if source.respond_to? :to_str
    source = source.to_str
  elsif source.respond_to? :to_io
    source = source.to_io.read
  elsif source.respond_to?(:read)
    source = source.read
  end
  if opts[:allow_blank] && (source.nil? || source.empty?)
    source = 'null'
  end
  result = parse(source, opts)
  recurse_proc(result, &proc) if proc
  result
end
```

The first line within the method:

```rb
opts = load_default_options.merge options
```

We can call the `JSON#load_default_options` in the console:

```rb
JSON.load_default_options

=> {:max_nesting=>false, :allow_nan=>true, :quirks_mode=>true, :create_additions=>true}
```

We can see there're four default options, what do they mean, we can get some from here [click me](https://devdocs.io/ruby~2.6/json#method-i-parse):

- max_nesting: The maximum depth of nesting allowed in the parsed data structures. Disable depth checking with :max_nesting => false. It defaults to 100./
- allow_nan: If set to true, allow NaN, Infinity and -Infinity in defiance of RFC 7159 to be parsed by the Parser. This option defaults to false.
- symbolize_names: If set to true, returns symbols for the names (keys) in a JSON object. Otherwise, strings are returned. Strings are the default.
- create_additions: If set to false, the Parser doesn't create additions even if a matching class and create_id was found. This option defaults to false.
- object_class: Defaults to Hash
- array_class: Defaults to Array

### WHY

referring to `JSON#parse`, back to see the source codes of `JSON#load`, The third to last line, there is `result = parse(source, opts)`, So `load` actually is a `parse` with four default options.

That is the reason:

```rb
JSON.load("123") #=> 123
JSON.parse("123", quirks_mode: true) #=> 123
```

another way, if the object to be parsed responds to  `to_io` meaning is a File, `load` still makes sense. However, parse do not.

Comment: This also shows that `JSON.load` doesn't use streaming, so has no performance or resource advantages over just loading the entire contents of a file into memory using `File.read` and then parsing with `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another difference: different options.
Common-use example (note `_keys` vs. `_names`):

```
JSON.load '{"key": "val"}', symbolize_keys: true
=> {"key" => "val"}         # parse option syntax silently ignored 

JSON.parse '{"key": "val"}', symbolize_keys: true
=> {:key => "val"}          # symbols, yay!

JSON.load '{"key": "val"}', symbolize_names: true
=> {:key => "val"}          # using the correct syntax for load
```

Comment: `JSON.load` does not ignore options. It just expects 3 arguments and the option you have provided is incorrect. 
`JSON.load('{"key": "val"}', nil, symbolize_names: true) #=> {:key => "val"}`

Comment: You're right of course in the fact that any method expects its own parameters. My emphasis however is in how similar these options are, plus the fact that incorrect options (keys) are silently ignored. I wasted some time figuring out I was using the wrong one, so I added this answer to the first SO search result I initially got, hoping the next guy will have a smoother course :) thanks for pointing out `::symbolize_names`.

Comment: and thank you for documenting it! :)  Sorry if I sounded terse, just didn't want people to get the wrong idea.